# locale can't be changed

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I'm trying to change Locale using primefaces in vain, here's my bean code :

```
// more imports here
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class DateBean implements Serializable{
  private Date startDate, endDate;

  private Locale locale = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale();

  public void setLocale(Locale locale) {
    this.locale = locale;
  }

  public Locale getLocale(){
    return locale;
   }

 public void changeLocale(String loc){
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    locale = new Locale(loc);
    context.getViewRoot().setLocale(locale);
 }
}
```

facelet :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" 
 xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
 <f:view locale="#{dateBean.locale}">
 <h:head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
 <title>Insert title here</title>
 <h:outputScript library="scripts" name="#{dateBean.locale}.js"></h:outputScript>
 </h:head>
 <h:body>
 <h:form>              
  <p:commandButton value="de" action="#{dateBean.changeLocale('de')}" >
     <p:ajax update="@form" process="@form"></p:ajax>
 </p:commandButton>  
 <p:calendar id="cc" value="#{dateBean.startDate}" required="true" showOn="both"  
 requiredMessage="Start date required"/>
 <p:message for="cc"></p:message>
 </h:form>
 </h:body>
 </f:view>
 </html>
```

Calendar locale does not change to deutsch when i click on the locale button, and i got no exception .
However it's like a breeze doing this task using old JSF2.* CommandButton component this way :

```
 <h:commandButton value="portugal" action="#{dateBean.changeLocale('pt')}" >
  <f:ajax render="@form"></f:ajax>
 </h:commandButton>
```

May you guys help me figure it out please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primefaces library doesn't provide German translation for its components. You need to download the javascript piece and attach it to your code. Then, make the calendar use the `locale` you want. Take a look at this [site](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/wiki/PrimeFacesLocales) and [here](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4912) you have more info about your issue.

You also are including a Javascript file depending on your locale (`<h:outputScript library="scripts" name="#{dateBean.locale}.js">`) that makes the javascript file to be included dinamically depending on your locale. Since you're only refreshing the `h:form` part with your ajax request, you could get in trouble with that, since this tag is rendered with the whole view, so your translation file is not available for your locale at the moment. Appropiate solution: just include all the javascript files you need since the begining.

Comment: I've already done so sir, the problem is not about .js languages, thanks anyway

Comment: Then there are two possibilities: Your `#{dateBean.locale}` is not acquiring the proper value or your calendar's locale is not being properly set. Why don't you try `locale="#{dateBean.locale}"` attribute in your calendar?

Comment: AFAK Calendar's locale attribute is not required, for it already gets changed using Action event, However it still not working after adding locale attribute, it really gets on my nerve, thanks anyway

Comment: Check out what your actual `#{dateBean.locale}` value is. Print it out on the screen.

Comment: It prints out en_US, then it only changes using event action button

Comment: Probably a problem about how you're loading the javascript file. If you load `<h:outputScript library="scripts" name="#{dateBean.locale}.js">`, when you update your view using Ajax, only your form is being updated, so the `de.js` you need is not being loaded. Try to always load the required javascript files and it should work.

Comment: that was not within the bounds of my thinking, May you clarify how to do that ? thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, problem's still there

Comment: I added outputscript tag for each locale, but locale still does not change.

Comment: I changed `process="@form"` to `process="@this"`, Now it works, thanks

Comment: Congrats, feel free to edit my answer with the final solution.